# Is it possible to do out of band oauth2 authentication using the github API

Tags: oauth-2.0, github-api

I'm writing a VBA client which needs to post to GitHub. I'd prefer to use Oauth2 for authentication to keep it in line with implementations in other languages.

When specifying the redirect_uri some oauth2 providers allow you to specify an out of band uri .. specifically

```
urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
```

Since the VBA app is not web based, I can't specify a real redirect_uri. Does anyone know whether the GitHub API can support some form of out of band OAUTH2 authentication like this, and if so, how to specify it in the GitHub Application console.